# Save description off listview item

Tags: android, eclipse, string, listview, save

I need to save the description in a string of an item selected on ListView.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having simple list item, You have to declare String variable inside your Activity class and register for itemclick event for listening the item clicks.

This is how i do :

```
 class YourActivity extends Activity{
     String my_selected_item_text=null;

    @override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
          //your stuffs here
          yourlistview.setOnItemClickListener(
          new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
               my_selected_item_text=(String)yourlistview.getItemAtPosition(position);
              //my_selected_item_text contains description of the String displayed in your ListView. now you can save that description anywhere you want....
         });
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is, that you can use string member variable of your activity in your listview